Map deserialization with moshi and retrofit
I have the below json response
{"page":2,
  "results":{
    "0":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"Jane"
    },
    "1":{
      "id":2,
      "name":"Joe"
    }
  }
}

and I am using moshi converter with retrofit to parse the response in an Android application.
can I structure my model as below
data class PersonList(
@Json(name = "page") val page: Int,
@Json(name = "results") val personList: List<Person>
)

 data class Person(val id: Int, val name: String)

and a deserializer as below
class PersonAdapter {
@FromJson
fun getPersonList(map: Map<String, Person>): List<Person> = map.entries.map { it.value }

}
since moshi has inbuilt support for map, will my FromJson convert the map to list?
what is the best approach here, other than reading through the json and convert?

Did you test it? Because that adapter will indeed work (just make sure to add it to your Moshi Builder).
I also wrote an alternative adapter that doesn't do the intermediate map, in case you're interested.
object ResultsAdapter {
  @FromJson fun fromJson(
    reader: JsonReader,
    personAdapter: JsonAdapter<Person>
  ): List<Person> {
    reader.beginObject()
    val results = mutableListOf<Person>()
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      reader.skipName()
      val person = personAdapter.fromJson(reader)
        ?: throw JsonDataException("Unexpected null at " + reader.path)
      results += person
    }
    reader.endObject()
    return unmodifiableList(results)
  }

  @ToJson fun toJson(
    writer: JsonWriter,
    results: List<Person>,
    personAdapter: JsonAdapter<Person>
  ) {
    writer.beginObject()
    for (i in results.indices) {
      val person = results[i]
      writer.name(i.toString())
      personAdapter.toJson(writer, person)
    }
    writer.endObject()
  }
}

Again, just make sure to add the adapter to your Moshi instance.
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
  .add(ResultsAdapter) // or your PersonAdapter
  .build()


Thanks for your response, I have tried the way it is described in question and I got com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER  for the id key. I know JsonReader can be used, but if it works out of the box , would have been better

@RajiAC Can you provide a failing test case or runnable example? Running your code works as expected. Perhaps your JSON structure isn't always as expected?
